# new changes not detected at runtime after migrating from angular 2 to angular 6

Tags: angular, npm, asp.net-core, migration, angular6

I migrate my angular 2 with DotNetCore project to angular 6 by running following command

```
  npm install -g npm-check-updates
  ncu -u
```

After migration, I am able to run my previous developed project but new changes added after migration are not detected.I used hard reload option as well but no use.any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

P.S:- we are not using angular-cli in our project.Its angular with MVC in .Net core.

Comment: Are you using the cache busting ? If the files produced by your compiler have the same name, they will be cached. You need to hit Ctrl + F5 to refresh your cache.

Comment: @trichetriche:I did..even use google chrome hard load option..still no luck

Answer (score 0):

use this in your tsconfig.json file

```
{
 "compileOnSave": true,
 "compilerOptions": {
 "target": "es5",
 "module": "commonjs",
 "moduleResolution": "node",
 "sourceMap": true,
 "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
 "experimentalDecorators": true,
 "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
 "noImplicitAny": true,
 "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
}
}
```

Comment: resolved. The issue was in my vendor.js file. Components have some error but Vendor.js file was not able to show that and loading old solution only.that's why I was not getting any new changes